# Pythonic code for conditional loop over array (Market Meaness Index)

Tags: python, arrays, algorithmic-trading

I'm just starting out with Python, all my previous experience being C++ type languages.

In the attempt to learn "good" Python I've been trying to convert this C-like function into Python.

```
var MMI(var *Data,int Length)
{
  var m = Median(Data,Length);
  int i, nh=0, nl=0;
  for(i=1; i<Length; i++) {
    if(Data[i] > m && Data[i] > Data[i-1])
      nl++;
    else if(Data[i] < m && Data[i] < Data[i-1])
      nh++;
  }
  return 100.*(nl+nh)/(Length-1);
}
```

I'm pretty sure I can do it easily with a for loop, but I've been trying to do it using a series of array operations, rather than an explicit loop. I came up with:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series 

def MMI( buffer, mmi_length ):
    window = Series( buffer[:mmi_length] )
    m      = window.median()

    nh = np.logical_and( [window > m], [window > window.shift(1)] ) 
    nl = np.logical_and( [window < m], [window < window.shift(1)] ) 
    nl = np.logical_and( [not nh], [nl] )

    return 100 * ( nh.sum() + nl.sum() ) / mmi_length
```

The final `np.logical_and( [not nh], [n] )` gives a "truth value ambiguous" error, which I don't understand, but more importantly I'm not sure whether this approach will actually yield a valid result in Python.

Could someone provide a pointer in how I should code this elegantly, or slap me on the head and tell me to just use a loop?

Ian

Comment: Ian, given your indicated interest goes into both ML & algo-trading, you may enjoy rather the **`numpy` strided-tricks >>> http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides** for series, which in both quant & ML models soon grow to shapes not feasible for InRAM processing. Given that, re-packing the huge amounts of data into a pandas abstraction does not yield to a surviveable implementation. If in doubts, benchmark the code on 1M, 10M, 100M rows of data to see the relaxation of performance ( which may obviously seem forgiving on tiny and small matrix sizes ... ).

Comment: Thank you - I will take a look, though to be honest I'm so new to this whole space that I've not yet reached a point where I have anything useful to apply to a large dataset!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is implicit, unlike C++ where you almost have to declare everything. Python, and numpy/pandas or other modules, have a ton of optimized functionality built-in - in order for you to work without a lot of loops or value by value comparison (what the modules do in the background, often is a for loop though - so don't think that it's necessarily faster, it's often just a pretty cover).

Now, let's look at your code

```
import numpy as np # no need for pandas here


def MMI( buffer, mmi_length ):
    # we will need to define two arrays here,
    # shift(n) does not do what you want
    window = np.asarray(buffer[1:mmi_length])
    window_shifted = np.asarray(buffer[:mmi_length-1])
    m = np.median(window)

    # instead using all these explicit functions simply do:
    nh = (window > m) & (window > window_shifted) 
    nl = (window < m) & (window < window_shifted) 
    nl = ~nh & nl                                # ~ inverts a lot of things,
                                                 # one of them are boolean arrays

    # this does the right thing
    return 100*(nh.sum()+nl.sum())/mmi_length
```

Now let's explain:

A Series is basically an array, in this context a series seems like an overkill. If you compare such an object with a scalar, you will get an array of booleans, expressing which value met the condition and which didn't (the same goes for comparing two arrays, it will result in boolean array expressing the value by value comparison).

In the first step, you compare an array to a scalar (remember, this will be a boolean array) and another array to a another array (we'll get to the shift part) and then want to logically and combine the result of the comparisons. Good thing is, that you want to combine two boolean arrays, this will work implicitly by the `&` operation.
The second step is analogous and will work implicitly the same.

In the third step, you want to invert a boolean array and combine it with another boolean array. Inversion is done by the `~` operator and can be used in lot's of other places to (e.g. for inverting subset selections, etc). You cannot use the `not` operator here, since its purpose is to convert its argument into a truth value (True/False) and return the opposite  - but what is the truth value of an array? The logical and combination of all components? It's not defined, therefore you get the `ambiguous` error.

The `sum()` of a boolean array is always the count of `True` values in the array, thus it will yield the right results.

The only problem with your code, is that if you apply `shift(1)` to this Series, it will prepend a `NaN` and truncate the last element of the Series, so that you end up with an equal length object. Now your comparisons are not yielding what you want anymore, because anything compared to a `numpy.NaN` will return `False`.
In order to overcome that, you can simply define a second array in the beginning (which then makes pandas obsolete), using the same syntax you already used for `window` before.

---

PS: a numpy array is not a python list (all of the above are numpy arrays!) A numpy array is a complex object that allows for all these operations, with standard python lists, you have to work your own for loops

Comment: Thank you - this is incredibly helpful and really advanced my understanding. Not least because for the life of me I could not figure out what the invert operator is in Python! In your final example code given, 'm=window.median()' does not work as only Series has a median() method, so I replaced that with 'm = np.median(window)'